# VC++ GetComputerName returns uppercase on Win10

Tags: visual-c++, windows-10

Why GetComputerName keeps original case for Win server 2012, but always returns uppercase for Win10?

Comment: The GetComputerName API function "retrieves the NetBIOS name of the local computer." According to Computer Names, "NetBIOS names, by convention, are represented in uppercase ...". Therefore, it looks like you are using the wrong API. What you probably want to retrieve instead is "the DNS host name of the local computer", which you can obtain by calling GetComputerNameEx(ComputerNamePhysicalDnsHostname, ...).

Comment: @JerryJeremiah You are correct, could you please add this as answer?

Comment: Also consider using getaddrinfo() and getnameinfo().

Answer (score 0):

the result of **`GetComputerName`** is same as the value in the Windows registry key **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ComputerName** 
so please verify your result with the above registry value.

Comment: The ComputerName I'm saying is the value for 'hostname' command output, or the value in System dialog, or the value where we can set the new one.

Comment: You can use WMI programme with the query **"select DNSHostName  from Win32_ComputerSystem"** to find the hostname of the system

Answer (score 0):

To get the correct computer name you can search in Registry from the path..
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\hostname

The exact computer name as stored in computername is stored here.
Whereas,
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ComputerName this will give the computername in uppercase irrespective of the name stored.